# compile glib 2.48 does not recognize pcre with utf support

Tags: gcc, utf-8, pcre, glib

I have compiled pcre 8.38 from source with `--enable-utf8 --enable-unicode-properties` and a `pcretest -C utf` retuns `1`.

a `which pcretest` returns `/home/mybin/bin/pcretest`

However when compiling `glib 2.48` using `PCRE_LIBS="/home/mybin/lib" PCRE_CFLAGS="/home/mybin/bin"` i get a `configure` error from configure.log

```
checking for PCRE... yes
checking for Unicode support in PCRE... no
configure: error: *** The system-supplied PCRE does not support Unicode properties or UTF-8.
```

is there something else I should check to get the `glib configure` to pass?

Comment: See `config.log` for more verbose details.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into his issue as well. Be sure you have $PCRE_INSTALL_DIR/lib in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well. That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

If internal glib pcre is acceptable option then you may use `--with-pcre` in  configure.

Comment: It is works. Thanks. Debian 10, glib-2.52.3, pcre-8.39.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you enable unicode during configuration:

```
./configure --enable-utf --enable-unicode-properties
```

and then `make`. Later, for installation use this:

```
make pkgconfigdir=/usr/lib/pkgconfig install
```

Answer (score 3):

Run `ldconfig` after `make install` step of `libpcre`. After that try `./configure` in glib.

Answer (score 2):

./configure tests UTF-8 support by compiling a small test program (line 27618) and running it:

```
#include <pcre.h>
int main () {
    int support;
    pcre_config (PCRE_CONFIG_UTF8, &support);
    if (!support)
        return 1;
    pcre_config (PCRE_CONFIG_UNICODE_PROPERTIES, &support);
    if (!support)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

If that test program can't be compiled and run properly or it returns 1 for any reason then ./configure will say that there isn't UTF-8 support.
Check that your operating system can find the shared libraries in your PCRE lib directory. You can do that by compiling the above test program and making sure it can run without crashing due to a missing shared library.

I had that problem but even when I fixed it Glib failed to detect UTF-8 support in PCRE. When that happens you could try editing ./configure to skip over that test but failing that test is hinting at there being some other problem so I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

I find following words in glib README, it works for me
Notes about GLib 2.48
 =====================

- The system copy of PCRE is now used by default to implement GRegex.
  Configure with --with-pcre=internal if a system PCRE version
  is unavailable or undesired

Answer (score 1):

PCRE_LIBS and PCRE_CFLAGS with just path is not enough.

In my case, compile glib-2.52.3 with pcre-8.38, i used
`PCRE_CFLAGS="/usr/local/include"`
`PCRE_LIBS="/usr/local/lib",`
and get a `The system-supplied PCRE does not support Unicode properties or UTF-8` result.
I followed the config.log, it post this
`configure:27740: checking for Unicode support in PCRE 
configure:27766: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 /usr/local/include  -pthread  conftest.c /usr/local/lib >&5 
/usr/local/include: file not recognized: Is a directory 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
configure:27766: $? = 1 
configure: program exited with status 1`

so i changed the flag content, become to this
`PCRE_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"`
`PCRE_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib"`
it tell me
`configure:27740: checking for Unicode support in PCRE 
configure:27766: gcc -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include  -pthread  conftest.c -L/usr/local/lib >&5 
/tmp/cc8eu7d8.o: In function 'main': 
/data1/rugalzhang/glib-2.52.3/conftest.c:178: undefined reference to 'pcre_config' 
/data1/rugalzhang/glib-2.52.3/conftest.c:181: undefined reference to 'pcre_config' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
configure:27766: $? = 1 
configure: program exited with status 1`

with that, make the final change
`PCRE_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"`
`PCRE_LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -lpcre"`
and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I did even another thing to make glib 2.52.3 compile with pcre 8.39

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/lib ./configure <...>`

where `$PREFIX/lib` is where libpcre.so lies.

Without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH, in config.log:

```
./conftest: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

modifying PCRE_CFLAGS or PCRE_LIBS did not help ...